# (AvaloniaUI) ArgumentException being thrown when OpenFileDialog is used in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, openfiledialog, argumentexception, avaloniaui

I am deploying my app to Windows 7, Windows 10, and Linux. At one point I am using OpenFileDialog to allow to user to pick a file path. This is working in Windows 10 and Linux, but when run in Windows 7, an ArgumentException is being thrown.

I've tried looking into the exception by displaying the exception message, which is "Value does not fall within expected range." I am not sure what this means. It works fine in Windows 10 so I don't know why it wouldn't work the same here.

I have a method GetPath() that gets the selected path using OpenFileDialog and a button clicked event that calls GetPath() and sets the result to a local variable.

```
public async Task<string> GetPath()
{
   OpenFileDialog dialog = new OpenFileDialog();
   dialog.Filters.Add(new FileDialogFilter() { Name = "Csv", Extensions = { "csv" } });

   string[] result = await dialog.ShowAsync(this);   //sets opened file to a stream

   string stream = string.Join(" ", result);   //converts string[] to string

   return stream;   //returns path to selected file
}

private async void MasterBrowse_Clicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
{
   string getPath = string.Empty;
   try
   {
   getPath = await GetPath();
   }

   catch (ArgumentException e)
   {
      await MessageBox.Show(this, "Make sure to select a file before continuing\n" + "Exception: " + e.Message, "Error: incorrect file", MessageBox.MessageBoxButtons.Ok);
   }
}
```

Expected:
GetPath() should OpenFileDialog and save the selected path as a string, then return it. MasterBrowse_Clicked() should get the returned string.

Actual:
ArgumentException thrown when OpenFileDialog.ShowAsync() is called.

Comment: There is nothing in Avalonia codebase that throws a plain ArgumentException without a custom error message. Examine the stack trace further.

Comment: I output the stack trace in a message box since I'm running it on Windows 7. Here is a snip of the stack trace I get when I catch the ArgumentException error: [link](https://imgur.com/a/PzgIVuG). I haven't worked with stack traces very much, so while I understand what its displaying I'm not exactly sure what to do with the information it's giving me in this case.

Comment: I decided to go ahead and test on another Windows 7 machine and the exception went away. I was testing on a Windows 7 VM so there must have been something wrong with the VM and not the code. Thanks anyway @kekekeks

Comment: The exception is thrown by the COM marshaller from E_INVALIDARG returned by Win32 API. You probably need `[STAThread]` for your `Main`